# Arcpy cant access SDE (Copy_management)

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I want to copy datasets using ArcPy (Python) from a file geodatabase to a SDE. But somehow I can not access my SDE properly. The error I get is the following:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000110: C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Verbindung mit sde.sde does not exist. Failed to execute Copy

```
import arcpy

CopyGDB = "C:\\Temp\\TempDB.gdb"
PasteSDE = "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.2\\ArcCatalog\\Verbindung mit sde.sde"

arcpy.env.workspace = CopyGDB
CopyGDBdatasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()

for fd in CopyGDBdatasets:
       arcpy.Copy_management(fd, PasteSDE + "\\" + fd, "feature dataset")
```

I am using a 32 bit version of Python (Version 2.7.5) and 32 bit Version of ArcGIS (Version 10.2).

I checked the SDE Connection file and the path is correct. In ArcCatalog, I can access my SDE properly.

[image: Database Properties]

Comment: Does `arcpy.ListDatasets` also give a empty list on the SDE database?

Comment: If you run this process for one dataset in the Desktop application. You can get the equivalent python script by right clicking the item in the "geoprocessing result window"

Comment: ok sorry, i double checked it. arcpy.ListDatasets() ist working correctly. I will delete this part from the question.

Comment: Try to print out the result of `PasteSDE + "\\" + fd` in the loop. and confirm it is valid. Also you could try to remove the spaces in the name of the sde connection file. arcpy\arcgis generally is not a fan of spaces.

Comment: Thanks alot. The tip with right clicking the "geoprocessing result window" is great. The Output python code from is it is working for one Dataset. I removed the spaces in my sde Connection file too. But i somehow can not use it in in my loop. If I use `code OutputDS = "C:/Users/me/AppData/Roamin/ESRI/Desktop10.2/ArcCatalog/MyTest.sde/GDI." + fd ` it will result in an error while executing copy. The tool seems to change the / in my Output path to \ .

Comment: You could try swapping the `/`'s with `\\\` in the code output.

Comment: Are you getting the same error as before from the Copy_managment tool?

Comment: I changed Copy_management to `code arcpy.Copy_management(in_data= SourceDS ,out_data= OutputDS,data_type="FeatureDataset")` OutputDS has the path i posted in my previous comment and SourceDS hat the path `code "C:/Temp/TempDB.gdb/"+ fd`. Im getting the following ERROR: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR000260: Error copying from "C:/Temp/TempDB.gdb/DS" to "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roamin\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\MyTest.sde\GDI.DS"

Comment: Is the connection file configured with a user that has access to create new datasets? If the code from the geoproccessing result was working, it should be possible to mimic that. But with that generic error message it's hard to see what the problem is..

Comment: The ERROR 000110 is a problem with the path.  I realize that's obvious but there still might be a problem.  Try changing your path variables for both SDE and file gdb to use the raw string prefix:
`CopyGDB = r"C:\Temp\TempDB.gdb"\n

PasteSDE = r"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Verbindung mit sde.sde"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that SDE Dataset Names are prefixed with the schema owner name and separated with a "." . File geodatabases do not support this convention

- You will need to parse fd to remove this using something like fd.split(".")

I prefer to use the raw sting decorator on the path so that I can copy it directly from the windows address bar or ArcGIS

- instead of "C:\\Temp\\TempDB.gdb" use **r**"C:\Temp\TempDB.gdb"
- Also use os.path.join for best practice

Remove the optional data type parameter, the keyword you are using is wrong

- the keyword is **"FeatureDataset"** per the [doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy.htm)

try:

```
import os
...
outFd = fd.split(".")[1]
arcpy.Copy_management(fd, os.path.join(PasteSDE, outFd))
```